# Event Bus Vs HandlerManager in GWT?

Tags: events, gwt, event-handling

When i working with one GWT project am using `MVP pattern` and `HandlerManager` for communicating on the application via Events. Now am implementing  History Machanisam on my project.
They(GWT tearm) used Class `EventBus` for managing the events.

When read some blog i foud `HandlerManger` is used for `Widgets` and `EventBus` for other application wide communication.

But i feel both of them have same functionalities, then whats the purpose of this two implemetations, or whats the difference between them .

please help me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`HandlerManager` is the ancestor of the `EventBus`, which was extracted from (factored out of) it.

The main difference is that a `HandlerManager` has a *source* that it enforces on the events being dispatched to it, whereas `EventBus` can dispatch events with no source (`fireEvent`) or with a given *dynamic* source (`fireEventFromSource`). You can then attach handlers to the `EventBus` that will only be triggered for events from a given source.

Within widgets, you want to enforce that the event source is the widget. For a global application-wide event bus, you either want no source, or a source *dynamically* set for each event, as needed (`RequestFactory` uses it for its `EntityProxyChange` events so you can listen only to events related to a given kind of `EntityProxy`)

Note: the javadoc for `HandlerManager` discourages using it for an application-wide event bus.

Comment: I noticed that Javadoc; doesn't really explain why, though.